# jQuery bind click event to id that has increasing number on every page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Here's what I have. A SharePoint 2010 custom view in a list web part. I have 6 categories and 4 sub-categories. Items do not have to have sub-category but do have to have a category.

The view shows the a blank sub-category witha number next to it. I'm trying to bind a click event to all of them but the ID increases on every page refresh. The base ID is titl[0-9]**[0-9]*. Then there is another ID underneath that I want to check as well, it is titl[0-9]*_[0-9]*1*.

So I've tried using the [regex selector for jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) and it doesn't bind correctly. It finds the object but doesn't bind correctly.

I need it to bind to the id and then be able to trigger the onclick event of the next tbody which is the 1_. Then check if the text of it is " " and if so hide the tbody.

My code:

```
$(":regex(id,titl[0-9]*-[0-9]_) td a").bind('click', function(){
  var parent = $(this);
  var child = $(this).next("tbody");
  var grandchild = $(this).next("tbody td a");
  //alert(parent + " | " + child + " | " + grandchild ); //always return undefined??
  // Everything below works if I can get the IDs correct for child and grandchild
  if($(grandchild).css('display')!='none'){
    $(grandchild).click();

    if($(grandchild).text()==" "){
      $(child).hide();
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: Why not give it a css class you can reference?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest you need to re-think your IDs - they should be consistent, really.

If you absolutely must work with a variable ID, you can use the "id" attribute in a selector as with any other attribute:

```
// Any element, ID starts with "titl"
$('[id^="titl"]')
```

To capture that and re-use it, I'd **really** suggest you're doing something wrong with your IDs. However, for completeness (although I can't stress enough how much you should try to avoid having to use this), something based on this should be a good (haha, yeah right) starting point

```
// Long-winded messy hideous foul code
var $title = $('[id^="titl"]'),
    title = $title.length && $title.eq(0).attr('id');
if (title !== 0)
{
    $('#' + title + ' #' + title + '1 td a').html('Ow.');
}
```

Comment: It's a SharePoint webpart. I don't have the option of doing something with the ID's. Trust me I'd love to have static ID's.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get this, but you can target any ID starting with `titl`, and then filter based on the ID in many other ways inside the function:

```
$('[id^="titl["]').on('click', function() {
    var check = this.id.charAt(10) == '_', //tenth character is underscore ?
        parent = $(this),
        child = $(this).next("tbody"),
        grandchild = $(this).next("tbody td a");

    if (check) {
        //element matching second selectortype clicked
    }else{
        if (grandchild.is(':visible')){
            grandchild.trigger('click');
            if (grandchild.text()==" ") child.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree about rethinking your ids if you have control over them. Even if you don't, the StartsWith selector will get you all of the higher level elements, and you can traverse to the lower level ones. Remember that chaining the selectors means that you can match on similar *patterns* in ids, not paying any attention to the actual *values*.

One other note: I've never needed to resort to a regex match with jQuery. The CSS3-like selectors are just far too powerful for that.

Comment: Marc, It's a sharepoint web part. Normally I'd write a new web part and use your SPServices, however I don't have that option this time. I have to use the list view web part.